# how set a method invisible for special class type in generic class in java

Tags: java, generics

I have two class (Admin, Patient) both extends User class and one generic class for them (UserDao`<T>`)

I want write some methods in UserDao`<T>` that visible just for one of Admin or Patient class.

```
public class UserDao<T extends User> {
private Connection connection;

public UserDao(Connection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
}

public <T extends Patient> boolean addPrescription(T t, Prescription prescription) {
    boolean isAdded = false;

    int patientId = t.getId();
    ArrayList<Item> items = prescription.getItems();

    ItemDao itemDao = new ItemDao(connection);
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(Constants.ADD_PATIENT_ID_PRESCRIPTIONS_QUERY);
        ps.setInt(1, patientId);

        int result = ps.executeUpdate();

        if (result == 1) {
            for (var item : items) {
                isAdded = itemDao.addItem(item);
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return isAdded;
}
```

}

but in Main Class I can see this method for both type

```
    UserDao<Patient> patientUserDao = new UserDao<>(DbConnection.getConnection());
    UserDao<Admin> adminUserDao = new UserDao<>(DbConnection.getConnection());
    Admin admin = new Admin();
    Patient patient = new Patient();
    Prescription prescription = new Prescription();
    patientUserDao.addPrescription(patient, prescription);
    adminUserDao.addPrescription(patient,prescription);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in Java.  Methods on a generic type must support all values of that generic type.

The closest thing you can do is write static helpers accepting the restricted types:

```
static boolean addPrescription(UserDao<Patient> patient, Prescription prescription) {
  ...
}
```